# Pandas dataframe merging with duplicates assigned to certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes.

```
data1 = {'col4':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'col5':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
     col4  col5                                                                                                                  
0    Tom    20                                                                                                                   
1   nick    21                                                                                                                   
2  krish    19                                                                                                                   
3   jack    18 


data2 = {'col1':['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'xxx','yyy', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'],
        'col2':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack','Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'col3':[110, 121, 119, 118,141,156,176,186]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
  col1   col2  col3                                                                                                              
0  xxx    Tom    110                                                                                                              
1  yyy   nick    121                                                                                                              
2  zzz  krish    119                                                                                                              
3  xxx   jack    118                                                                                                              
4  yyy    Tom    141                                                                                                              
5  xxx   nick    156                                                                                                              
6  yyy  krish    176                                                                                                              
7  zzz   jack    186
```

I need to have col5 in my df2 dataframe based on col2 and col4. The value of col5 for the repeated values in col2 should be assigned 0, except for the first value. For example, Tom is getting repeated and only the first value of Tom(index 0) is assigned to 20 after merging with df1. The other value of Tom should be 0 (index 4).
I want the resultant dataframe column as :

```
  col1   col2  col3  col5                                                                                                            
0  xxx    Tom   110   20                                                                                                           
1  yyy   nick   121   21                                                                                                          
2  zzz  krish   119   19                                                                                                           
3  xxx   jack   118   18                                                                                                           
4  yyy    Tom   141    0                                                                                                            
5  xxx   nick   156    0                                                                                                          
6  yyy  krish   176    0                                                                                                         
7  zzz   jack   186    0
```

Please help me to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge and then apply the condition using [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`series.duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
final = df2.merge(df1, how='left', left_on='col2', right_on='col4')
final.col5 = np.where(final.duplicated(['col2', 'col5']), 0, final.col5)
print(final)
```

---

```
  col1   col2  col3   col4  col5
0  xxx    Tom   110    Tom    20
1  yyy   nick   121   nick    21
2  zzz  krish   119  krish    19
3  xxx   jack   118   jack    18
4  yyy    Tom   141    Tom     0
5  xxx   nick   156   nick     0
6  yyy  krish   176  krish     0
7  zzz   jack   186   jack     0
```

Comment: Tom and nick can have same value ,duplicates of col2 must be 0 except for the first occurence